# Next.JS + Firebase Web app Error : window is not defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

### Stack Trace

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: window is not defined

Call Stack
updateDehydratedSuspenseComponent
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (16344:0)
updateSuspenseComponent
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (16044:0)
beginWork$1
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (17357:0)
beginWork
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (25650:0)
performUnitOfWork
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (24501:0)
workLoopSync
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (24217:0)
renderRootSync
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (24182:0)
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23321:0)
workLoop
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (261:0)
flushWork
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (230:0)
MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (537:0)
```

### File where the error originates

src/components/Admin/AdminLogin.tsx

```js
"use client";

import { auth } from "@/firebase/firebase";
import { FirebaseError } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useState, FormEventHandler } from "react";

function AdminLogin() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const router = useRouter(); // NextJS Navigation

  const signIn: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setError("");
    try {
      if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        const auth = getAuth();
        await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      }
    } catch (error: FirebaseError | any) {
      setError(error.message);
    }
    if (auth.currentUser) {
      router.push("/dashboard");
    }
  };

  return (
    // A bunch of JSX....
  );
}

export default AdminLogin;
```

### Possible Source of Origin

1. I have researched and found that the error might be originating from `signIn()` where the firebase's `signInWithEmailAndPassword` is getting used.
2. Also I am using the NextJS's new app router and typescript.
3. This error is not breaking anything but I just what to keep my app clean and error free.
4. There are similar question on stack overflow, but in that people are referencing the window directly, but i am not referencing it anywhere, i think the window is used by some other method/function.

Previosly inside the try block:

```
try {
  const auth = getAuth();
  await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
} catch (error) {
  setError(error.message);
}
```

From some sources i tried the solution as specified in the main file but it did't work.

Comment: Why don't you do some debugging to figure out the exact line of code here that runs just before you see the error?